# Hide console in C system() function, Win

Tags: c, windows, cmd, system

I am coding a C program in Dev-C++, and I need to use a couple of Windows (CMD) commands. It is easy, but when the command in the system() function is executed, the program runs the console in the execution.

An example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

    int main()
    {
      system("if not exist c:\my_docs\doc.txt (xcopy /Y doc.txt c:\my_docs\)"); // Cmd command
      system("pause");
      return 0;
    }
```

Exists other function, or a modification that do not shows the console?

Thanks you! Best regards.

Comment: Dev C++ is obsolete, I strongly recommend you pick an other one

Comment: How do you expect the "pause" command to work if there's no console window showing?

Also cmd.exe is a console application - there's no easy way for you to prevent the console window from showing.

Comment: @Larry Osterman, Nice to see you on SO Larry; I enjoy the blog!

Comment: My god, last stable version of Dev-C++ is from 2005 ... it is a bit obsolete, yes. +1 to Sam.

Comment: Yes Larry, I also thought this, but ask is free, and there is no similar questions in stackoverflow ;-)

Comment: Use Code::Blocks instead of Dev-C++

Comment: have you sovle the problem? I want to exeucute **adb shell am broadcast -a NotifyServiceStart** in C and hiding the console. The following answer not work.

Answer (score 28):

You can use `WinExec("your cmd command", SW_HIDE);` instead of `system("cmd command")`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm form the days of 16-bit Windows, but forgot this function. It came in handy in an important scenario for WIndows LogOn(Cred. Provider DLL), where CreateProcess() is not allowed by MS, and system() has a console window at the back(and hence making it not an attractive option). Thank u!

Comment: It is `system("chcp 936")` in my code. It is setting the cosole to show Chinese characters. If I run it in another app, it would be futile.

Comment: For people coming here with their own scenarios, please note the limitations of `WinExec` like if the executable is on a path with spaces.

Answer (score 14):

You can do it with CreateProcess.

```
STARTUPINFOW si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

if (CreateProcessW(command, arg, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks you, I will test it. It is not exactly what I was looking for, but is a good answer.

Comment: I tried your code in *windows 7*, but it doesn't work. I want to execute **adb shell am broadcast -a NotifyServiceStart**. By the way, I have add the **adb** into the **PATH**, and **system()** can run this line well.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

"The string can specify the full path and file name of the module to execute or it can specify a partial name. In the case of a partial name, the function uses the current drive and current directory to complete the specification. The function will not use the search path. This parameter must include the file name extension; no default extension is assumed."

Answer (score 3):

As FigBug stated, CreateProcess() is the way to go, but I don't think that CreateProcess() can execute a shell if statement. You may need to pass it something like this as a command:

```
"cmd.exe /c \"if not exist c:\my_docs\doc.txt (xcopy /Y doc.txt c:\my_docs\)\""
```

But a better solution might be to use [CreateFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) to test if a file exists and [CopyFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363851%28VS.85%29.aspx) to copy it.

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: My answer is not necessarily tailored to your specific question, but this Q&A is the top [Google result](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+system()+without+new+command+prompt) for "Windows system without command prompt" and other similar queries.

Here's a way to execute commands without a new `cmd.exe` window. Based on [Roland Rabien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1597315/6850771) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx), I've written a working function.

```
#include "AtlBase.h"
#include "AtlConv.h"
  int windows_system(const char *cmd) {
    PROCESS_INFORMATION p_info;
    STARTUPINFO s_info;
    DWORD ReturnValue;
    CA2T programpath(cmd);

    memset(&s_info, 0, sizeof(s_info));
    memset(&p_info, 0, sizeof(p_info));
    s_info.cb = sizeof(s_info);

    if (CreateProcess(programpath, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, &s_info, &p_info)) {
      WaitForSingleObject(p_info.hProcess, INFINITE);
      GetExitCodeProcess(p_info.hProcess, &ReturnValue);
      CloseHandle(p_info.hProcess);
      CloseHandle(p_info.hThread);
    }
    return ReturnValue;
  }
```

Works on all Windows platforms. Call just like you would `system()`.

Comment: I am using MinGW, and I get `fatal error: AtlBase.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: What are AtlBase.h and AtlConv.h?

Answer (score 1):

```
int win_system(const char *command)
{
    // Windows has a system() function which works, but it opens a command prompt window.
    
    char            *tmp_command, *cmd_exe_path;
    int         ret_val;
    size_t          len;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info = {0};
    STARTUPINFOA        startup_info = {0};

    
    len = strlen(command);
    tmp_command = malloc(len + 4);
    tmp_command[0] = 0x2F; // '/'
    tmp_command[1] = 0x63; // 'c'
    tmp_command[2] = 0x20; // <space>;
    memcpy(tmp_command + 3, command, len + 1);
    
    startup_info.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOA);
    cmd_exe_path = getenv("COMSPEC");
    _flushall();  // required for Windows system() calls, probably a good idea here too
    
    if (CreateProcessA(cmd_exe_path, tmp_command, NULL, NULL, 0, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &startup_info, &process_info)) {
        WaitForSingleObject(process_info.hProcess, INFINITE);
        GetExitCodeProcess(process_info.hProcess, &ret_val);
        CloseHandle(process_info.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(process_info.hThread);
    }
    
    free((void *) tmp_command);
    
    return(ret_val);
}
```

Comment: Could you include some explanation/commentary on your code block?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).