# Suppress console when calling "system" in C++

Tags: c++, console, system, system-calls

I'm using the `system` command in C++ to call some external program, and whenever I use it, a console window opens and closes after the command finishes.

How can I avoid the opening of a console window? I would be happy if the solution could be platform-independent. I would also like for my program to wait until the command is finished.

Comment: duplicate with better answers (for Windows): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597289/hide-console-in-c-system-function-win

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're using windows.

On Linux (and *nix in general), I'd replace the call to `system` with calls to `fork` and `exec`, respectively.  On windows, I think there is some kind of spawn-a-new-process function in the Windows API—consult the documentation.

When you're running shell commands and/or external programs, your program is hard to make platform-independent, as it will depend on the platform having the commands and/or external programs you're running.

Comment: Generally speaking, you are right about programs being platform-dependent when using shell commands. However, in this case, I'm making sure that the external program is installed on the machine I'm using. It's not a simple shell command. Regarding your answer - It's possible to use CreateProcess for windows and fork+exec for unix, but I was hoping to solve this more elegantly.

Comment: what's not elegant about CreateProcess/fork+exec? If you wrap it in a nice class, you have a very elegant way to start processes, plus you can easily add options like redirecting output/input ect.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably the easiest and maybe the best way, this will also make it so that your program doesn't freeze while running this command.
At first don't forget to include the Windows header using;

```
#include <Windows.h>
```

Then you need to use the following function to run your command;

```
WinExec("your command", SW_HIDE);
```

*Note; The `WinExec` method has been deprecated for over a decade. It still works fine today though. You shouldn't use this method if not required.*

... instead of the way you **don't** want to use;

```
system("your command");
```

Comment: I'd hardly call WinExec the "best" way, given it's been deprecated for over 17 years.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure about it so thats why I said maybe

Comment: Worked fine to me, even if deprecated I have to upvote since I was searching for hours. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to execute commands without a new `cmd.exe` window. Based on [Roland Rabien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1597315/6850771) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx), I've written a working function:

```
int windows_system(const char *cmd)
{
  PROCESS_INFORMATION p_info;
  STARTUPINFO s_info;
  LPSTR cmdline, programpath;

  memset(&s_info, 0, sizeof(s_info));
  memset(&p_info, 0, sizeof(p_info));
  s_info.cb = sizeof(s_info);

  cmdline     = _tcsdup(TEXT(cmd));
  programpath = _tcsdup(TEXT(cmd));

  if (CreateProcess(programpath, cmdline, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, &s_info, &p_info))
  {
    WaitForSingleObject(p_info.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(p_info.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(p_info.hThread);
  }
}
```

Works on all Windows platforms. Call just like you would `system()`.

Comment: this doesn't return an int, I suggest returning the exit code from GetExitCodeProcess (std system returns this value)

Answer (score 1):

Errm. `CreateProcess` or `ShellExecute`.

Answer (score 0):

exec() looks quite platform independant as it is POSIX. On windows, it's _exec() while it's exec() on unix: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/431x4c1w(VS.71).aspx