# call default windows executables in C program

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I used `system()` function to call `certmgr.exe` in my C code.
Once I start my executable, a command promt appears showing certificate successfully installed.

But I dont want the command promt to be opened. How to do that??

any other ways available to call the "exe's" in C language..

thanks,,,

Comment: thanks all for ur replies... Upvoted all...

Comment: ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, ".\\certifications\\CertMgr.exe", "/add .\\certifications\\MYcertificate.cer /s /r localMachine root", NULL, SW_HIDE ) I use the above command and still a console window opens on clicking my exe....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this on Windows is to call [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx). Pass `SW_HIDE` to make sure that no console window is shown.

You could alternatively use [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) but it's a little trickier to call. Use the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag to suppress the console window.

Comment: ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, ".\\certifications\\CertMgr.exe", "/add .\\certifications\\MYcertificate.cer /s /r localMachine root", NULL, SW_HIDE ) I use the above command and still a console window opens on clicking my exe....

Comment: What about CreateProcess with the CREATE_NO_WINDOW flag. Sometimes that is the only solution.

Comment: ya I tried with createProcess also again am getting a console window.. CreateProcess(".\\certifications\\CertMgr.exe", "/add .\\certifications\\MYcertificate.cer /s /r localMachine root", NULL, NULL, FALSE,CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi );

Comment: It looks like CertMgr is creating a console window in spite of you. Try this code with some other console apps and you should see that they remain hidden.

Comment: cermgr works fine with python code without opening a console window... subprocess.Popen('.\certifications\CertMgr.exe /add .\certifications\\MYcertificate.cer /s /r localMachine trustedPublishers', shell=True)

Comment: Also, what are you passing in the lpStartupInfo parameter to CreateProcess?

Comment: no the application starts with this command only. so console window is not openend...si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

Comment: I do exactly the same in one of my programs and no window shows. Strange. The only difference I can see is that I pass `TRUE` for inherit handles but surely that won't explain the difference.

Comment: where both shellexecute and create process opens a console window

Comment: Answered by T.E.D in this link helped me finally... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030331/system-function-opens-a-window                                                      Others have mentioned using CreateProcess (presumably to redirect the output).

The general reason this happens is that the program you are running via "system" is a command-line program. If it is something you compile yourself, you can get rid of the console window by building it as a GUI program instead. You should be able to do this by including Windows.h and using WinMain() as your entry point instead of main()

Comment: sorry for the mess david.. I havent said you that am using mingw compiler. and using main as starting point.

Comment: Ah, the console is created by your app! It never occurred to me that might be the reason!

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use system to run anything.. this is why: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/

You can use ShellExecute to run applications [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx) Pass SW_HIDE and you're done.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to run `cmd.exe` silently/in background. However, do look up the `start` command and its associated `/B` option:

> Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.
>
> START ["title"] [/D path] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
>         [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL]
>         [/AFFINITY ] [/WAIT] [/B] [command/program]
>         [parameters]
>
> [...]
>       B           Start application without creating a new window. The
>                   application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application
>                   enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt
>                   the application.

You'll be better off with [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

WINAPI has a [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function that you could use to run another executable. There are several arguments to this function which *may* provide a mechanism for not displaying the console window of `certmgr.exe` (from [process creation flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) argument):

> CREATE_NO_WINDOW
>   The process is a console application that is being run without a console window. Therefore, the console handle for the application is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by T.E.D in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030331/system-function-opens-a-window) helped me finally...

This may help some one in future...

Others have mentioned using CreateProcess (presumably to redirect the output). The general reason this happens is that the program you are running via "system" is a command-line program. If it is something you compile yourself, you can get rid of the console window by building it as a GUI program instead. You should be able to do this by including Windows.h and using WinMain() as your entry point instead of main()

Comment: am using mingw as compiler and shell execute still opens a console with main as starting point. I changed it to WinMain() and compiled with -mwindows switch.