# Hiding console command used while using system()? C++ Linux

Tags: c++, linux

Well, I will put it plain and simple: I am a C++ pleb. Still trying to learn though.

My question is: is it possible to run a command though the terminal using system() command without letting the command be shown in the console/terminal?

Example:

```
system("sudo service sshd start") ;
Output: Sudo service sshd start
```

Where as I want:

```
system("sudo service sshd start") ;
output: (Blank)
```

Note: I am on linux.

Comment: Use [`popen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) from the GNU libc.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the symptom. What I see is the output of the command, not the command itself. Are you asking how to suppress a command's output? If so, it has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Supress console when calling "system" in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802471/supress-console-when-calling-system-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `system` standard library function starts up a subshell and executes the provided string as a command within that subshell. (Note that a subshell is simply a process running a shell interpreter; the particular shell interpreter invoked by `system` will depend on your system. No terminal emulator is used; at least, not on Unix or Unix-like systems.)

The `system` function does not reassign any file descriptors before starting the subshell, so the command executes with the current standard input, output and error assignments. Many commands will output to stdout and/or stderr, and those outputs will not be supressed by `system`.

If you want the command to execute silently, then you can redirect stdout and/or stderr in the command itself:

```
system("sudo service sshd start >>/dev/null 2>>/dev/null") ;
```

Of course, that will hide any error messages which might result from the command failing, so you should check the return value of `system` and provide your own error message (or log the information) if it is not 0.

This really has very little to do with the `system` call or the fact that you are triggering the subshell from within your own executable. The same command would have the same behaviour if typed directly into a shell.

Comment: You can also use `system("sudo service sshd start &> /dev/null");`. It's shorter and does exactly the same.

Comment: @marccoll: `&>` is a bash extensión, and there is no guarantee that `system` invokes `bash`. It might work on your machine but it cannot be relied upon in general.

Comment: Working fine, even on Code::Blocks IDE debug mode. Thanks you. But I am using `>` instead of `>>`. Any problem with that?

Comment: @sopalajo: the semantics of `>` involves truncating the target file, and on some implementations truncating `/dev/null` might not be petmitted. (On others, like Linux, it silently does nothing.) So it is conventional to use `>>` in order to append to `/dev/null`, which is guaranteed to work.