# Don't open console output with system()

Tags: c++, console, ping, dev-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide console in C system() function, Win.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597289/hide-console-in-c-system-function-win)

Hi guys I have a little problem, I need to ping a lot of PC, so in my program i call the function system() with "ping -n 1 > tmp.txt", but I don't want that the console window is shown.

How can I do it?

P.S.: I use dev c++ :D

thx

Comment: Do you mean that the application should run in the background?

Comment: Which platform? Which os? What is dev c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what you might be looking for here [Hide a window in C++](http://hackerslife.blogspot.com/2005/01/hide-window-in-c.html)

And also [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/68114-good-or-bad/page__hl__beep)  I guess the freeconsole() method is what you are needing?

Comment: Er.... we were just being helpful,  have you found the answer? If you have, go ahead and post it

Comment: I also downvoted your answer because it doesn't actually help the OP. Your answer doesn't address the question (if you tried these methods you'd see that they don't work in this context).

Comment: That's ok, please do post the answer when you get it, I am now really interested in seeing it

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly hard to do this cleanly.
A better approach might be to google "ping.c" and choose one of the many implementations, then rip the guts out of it and make your own ping function.  This will be faster and give you more control.

Answer (score 1):

See this question :

[Hide console in C system() function, Win](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597289/hide-console-in-c-system-function-win)

Comment: Looks like someone is angry here... please explain the downvotes

Comment: My apologies. I just received bad news, and I think it caused me to downvote when I normally never downvote. The reason I did it is because if you link to a duplicate, this is not an answer. You should put it in a comment as this means the question should be closed. I can't retract the downvote, but in my defense it's at least somewhat warranted :P

Comment: I upvoted one of your other answers :)