# Hiding command prompt called by system();

Tags: c++, windows

Goodday, I have script,that loops all files in directory, but I need to hide console while looping them this way.
Here is part of script:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

 int GetFilesInDirectory(const char * dir,string dest[],unsigned int max){
    string loc=dir;
    int ctr=0;
    if(loc.length()>2)
        if(loc.substr(loc.length()-2,1)=="\\")
            loc=loc.substr(0,loc.length()-1);
    string opcommand;
    string delcommand;
    if(loc.length()>2){
        opcommand="cd "+(loc)+" && dir /s /b /a > tmpfile.cpptmp";
        delcommand="cd "+(loc)+" && del tmpfile.cpptmp";
    } else {
        opcommand="dir /s /b /a > tmpfile.cpptmp";
        delcommand="del tmpfile.cpptmp";
    }
    system(opcommand.c_str());
    ifstream f;
    string line;
    string fileloc;
    if(loc.length()>2)
        fileloc=(loc)+"\\tmpfile.cpptmp";
    else fileloc="tmpfile.cpptmp";
    f.open(fileloc,ios::binary);
    while(f.good()){
        getline(f,line);
        if(line.length()>1&&ctr<max){
            dest[ctr]=line;
            ctr++;
        }
    }
    f.close();
    system(delcommand.c_str());
    return ctr;
}
int main() {
    FreeConsole();
    const unsigned int filescountmax=16184;

    string files[filescountmax];
    int count=GetFilesInDirectory("\\",files,filescountmax);
    string ext;
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
            //some script

    }
}
```

When process starts, it hides it self, but after while it shows up cmd.exe, which closes it self.
By the way, I know there are other ways to loop files in directory, but this is easiest way to loop also files in subdirs and subdirs of subdirs and so on.
Can you help me, please?

Comment: I think `CreateProcess` can be used to make a `system` call without showing a command prompt.

Comment: @WaleedKhan, I'm pretty sure you can specify the fourth argument to `WinMain`, so as long as the process uses it to determine the state, that'd be right.

Comment: If you want to list and delete files in a directory, why not use the Windows API functions provided for that?  There's a [tutorial on listing directory contents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for example.  Executing `cmd.exe` to do these things is a little silly — it's like you've written a batch file in C++.

Comment: Or you can use boost and have the solution be cross-platform. You could even try out TR2's `<filesystem>` header.

Comment: I have no idea how to use CreateProcess :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is analog of system function I've wrote for such tasks.

```
int system_hidden(const char *cmdArgs)
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo;
    STARTUPINFO sinfo;

    /*
     * Allocate and hide console window
     */
    AllocConsole ();
    ShowWindow (GetConsoleWindow(), 0);

    memset (&sinfo, 0, sizeof (sinfo));
    sinfo.cb = sizeof (sinfo);
    CreateProcess (NULL, (char*)cmdArgs,
                   NULL, NULL, false,
                   0,
                   NULL, NULL, &sinfo, &pinfo);
    DWORD ret;
    while (1)
    {
        HANDLE array[1];
        array[0] = pinfo.hProcess;
        ret = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects (1, array, false, INFINITE,
                                         QS_ALLPOSTMESSAGE);
        if ((ret == WAIT_FAILED) || (ret == WAIT_OBJECT_0))
            break;
        /*
         * Don't block message loop
         */
        MSG msg;
        while (PeekMessage (&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage (&msg);
            DispatchMessage (&msg);
        }
    }

    DWORD pret;
    GetExitCodeProcess (pinfo.hProcess, &pret);
//    FreeConsole ();
    return pret;
}
```

Comment: Rather than explicitly allocating and then hiding a console window, use the CREATE_NO_WINDOW flag in the CreateProcess call.

Comment: Anyway, it does nothing :( 
I tried system_hidden("echo hi>text.txt"); and nothing happened, application crashed

Comment: @DieMeine: two problems; firstly, that code won't compile as-is in a Unicode application, you'll need to change CreateProcess to CreateProcessA.  Secondly, CreateProcess doesn't use the shell, so internal commands such as echo and output redirection aren't valid. You'll need to explicitly invoke the shell: system_hidden("cmd /c echo hi > test.txt")

Comment: @Harry Johnston, thank you for finding inaccuracies in the code. I do not have Visual Studio near at hand.

Comment: Also thanks to Harry Johnston, it helped much, but to be fair, I used alexander's code, so that's an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the subsystem to make Windows hide the console. Add this command in your source code:

`#pragma comment(linker, "/subsystem:\"windows\" /entry:\"mainCRTStartup\"" )`

Or, you can try the `CreateProcess` function with the flag `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`.

Comment: I am trying this:
CreateProcess(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",LPWSTR(cmd),0,0,false,CREATE_NO_WINDOW,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi), but it does not work :(
char * cmd="echo hello >textfile.txt";

Comment: @DieMeine: the second argument to CreateProcess needs to be a wchar_t buffer (it must be writable memory).  Alternatively, use CreateProcessA; you're allowed to call that with a const char *.

Comment: You can try this: _TCHAR *cmd = L"echo hello >textfile.txt"

Comment: @user1692432: that won't work, the second argument to CreateProcessW cannot be a constant string, plus the shell command to be executed needs to be prefixed with /c.  Like this: wchar_t cmd[] = L"cmd /c echo hello > testfile.txt"

Comment: @DieMeine: check the return code from CreateProcess, if it is zero then call GetLastError to get the error code.

Answer (score 0):

I note that the accepted answer is a bit too complex. Here's a simpler way to execute commands without a new `cmd.exe` window. Based on [this answer by Roland Rabien's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1597315/6850771) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
int windows_system(const char *cmd)
{
  PROCESS_INFORMATION p_info;
  STARTUPINFO s_info;
  LPSTR cmdline, programpath;

  memset(&s_info, 0, sizeof(s_info));
  memset(&p_info, 0, sizeof(p_info));
  s_info.cb = sizeof(s_info);

  cmdline     = _tcsdup(TEXT(cmd));
  programpath = _tcsdup(TEXT(cmd));

  if (CreateProcess(programpath, cmdline, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, &s_info, &p_info))
  {
    WaitForSingleObject(p_info.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(p_info.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(p_info.hThread);
  }
}
```

Works on all Windows platforms. Call just like you would `system()`.

Comment: That won't work as expected if the command has any arguments, or is a built-in command rather than an executable.  It also won't suppress the console window for a command-line executable.

Answer (score 0):

I use this, only support run block cmd. like create shortcat in destktop, like open notepad.exe edit file, and so on.

```c
#define MAX_SYSTEM_PROGRAM (4096)
static int windows_system(const wchar_t *cmd)
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION p_info;
    STARTUPINFO s_info;
    DWORD ReturnValue;

    memset(&s_info, 0, sizeof(s_info));
    memset(&p_info, 0, sizeof(p_info));
    s_info.cb = sizeof(s_info);

    wchar_t utf16cmd[MAX_SYSTEM_PROGRAM] = {0};
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, cmd, -1, utf16cmd, MAX_SYSTEM_PROGRAM);
    if (CreateProcessW(NULL, utf16cmd, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, &s_info, &p_info))
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(p_info.hProcess, INFINITE);
        GetExitCodeProcess(p_info.hProcess, &ReturnValue);
        CloseHandle(p_info.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(p_info.hThread);
    }
    return ReturnValue;
}
```